# Parse elements from HTML

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing

I'm looking to just create a csv file of animal hospitals by state. I think my selecting of html is incorrect. I want to iterate through the elements selecting the right tags to parse the state, name, address, phone #.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

link = "https://vcahospitals.com/find-a-hospital/location-directory"
response = requests.get(link, allow_redirects = False) #get page data from server, block redirects
sourceCode = response.content #get string of source code from response
htmlElem = html.document_fromstring(sourceCode) #make HTML element object

print(sourceCode)
```

[Example page html. I've tried selecting all div elements as classes][1]

[I would think this grabs all the state hospitals, but it only prints out one state's worth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uasN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indented the print statement in your code wrong.

```
for el in state_hospitals:
    text = el.text_content()

    # indented in the for block.
    print (text)
```

Comment: awesome! That did help. So simple(I also got it to work by chaning my div) Would you have an idea about separating out the columns for: state, address, phone etc within that for loop? Thanks again! I appreciate it @sachin

Comment: You can accept this answer as correct, if it did solve your problem. Apart from that, you can use string operations to do that task.